# Don't want NLTK word tokenize to tokenize a single word 'gotta' into 'got' and 'ta'

Tags: python, nltk

I got input string as below. And when I use nltk.word_tokenize it gives me a split of single word 'gotta' into 'got' and 'ta'. I don't want that happening and I want to token it as single token 'gotta' itself. I'm not sure why it is happening. Any help to avoid this or advice as to why it is happening such way ? Test code below.

```
test = "Sorry times up  I gotta split"
output = nltk.word_tokenize(test)
print output
In [22]: ['Sorry', 'times', 'up', 'I', 'got', 'ta', 'split']
```

In the program I'm working on, after pre-processing, my word-to-index has them as single word gotta. But when tokenizing the entire sentence, it's different. Hence facing error later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try preprocessing `gotta` -> `got-ta`:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> sent = "Sorry times up  I gotta split"
>>> word_tokenize(sent)
['Sorry', 'times', 'up', 'I', 'got', 'ta', 'split']
>>> sent = "Sorry times up  I got-ta split"
>>> word_tokenize(sent)
['Sorry', 'times', 'up', 'I', 'got-ta', 'split']
```

Also, you can use other tokenizers, e.g. toktok:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.toktok import ToktokTokenizer
>>> toktok = ToktokTokenizer()
>>> sent = "Sorry times up  I gotta split"
>>> toktok.tokenize(sent)
[u'Sorry', u'times', u'up', u'I', u'gotta', u'split']
```

or moses:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesTokenizer
>>> moses = MosesTokenizer()
>>> moses.tokenize(sent)
[u'Sorry', u'times', u'up', u'I', u'gotta', u'split']
```